# How do I put table captions in the margin?

Tags: captions, marginpar

I have a two column document and need to display two tables alongside each other, with the caption in the margin. I've hit a wall with it -- I use `table*` float to span two columns with one figure and then `minipages` inside the figure to construct the tables.

This works, but how do I get the margin text to be alongside the floating tables? Also, is it possible to use a `caption` so I can `\Cref` the `label` in the document body?

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    11pt,
    twoside,
    twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[
    top=2cm,
    bottom=3cm,
    hmarginratio=4:1]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[9]

\begin{table*}[tbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rr}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Reported FPS}   &   \textbf{Count}   \\
        \midrule
        $12$    &   $1646$  \\
        $14$    &   $25$    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}
\end{minipage}%
%
\hskip2em\relax
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccr}
\toprule
\textbf{Dimensions} & \textbf{Standard} & \textbf{Count}      \\
\midrule
$352\times288$      & CIF   & $129$\\
$360\times288$      & --    & $560$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\end{table*}
\marginpar{
    \begin{minipage}{35mm}
        \raggedright \emph{\textbf{
        Table 2. Suspendisse vitae erat vitae ante aliquam condimentum.}}
    \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Give a look to `memoir` document class. It has an embedded `sidecaption` environment that work out of the box.

Comment: Try `\setlength\marginparwidth{1.6in}` in the preamble, though I don't quite get the full extent of your MWE (where the table itself should go)

Comment: The tables are in the right place, I need the caption to appear in the margin next to them, not on the first page next to the lipsum text. It's a vertical alignment problem.

Comment: The \marginpar is (and must be) outside the table, so it will not float with the table.  \marginnote (from the marginnote package) can be used inside the table.  Second, \marginpar (or \marginnote) already uses a \parbox, so the minipage is redundant.  Third, unless you increase the margin (and \marginparwidth) it will look very ugly.

Comment: Thanks John. I use `hmarginratio=4:1` to get wide gutters starting on the left for odd pages. `\marginnote` always puts the right in the right margin. How do I move it to the gutter side?

Comment: There are several different solutions.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185517/marginpar-marginnote-hint-to-column?s=1|1.0622 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247449/making-marginnote-to-appear-either-side-of-twocolumn-twoside-document-part-ii?s=3|0.5596 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226847/making-marginnote-to-appear-either-side-of-twocolumn-twoside-document?s=5|0.4493